# db.collection.find not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

On my [project](https://github.com/tumanov-alex/online-shop) with node and mongodb db.collection.find just not working. In routes.js file there is a function `getUser()` that tried to find a user by user_id, but finds nothing. I tried to do the same with same parameters on console and everything works fine.

How to invoke the error: go to your profile page, create an item and redirect back to the profile page, then refresh it. Because of that a profile.ejs file can't be executed.

```
function getUser(user_id) {
    var items;
    User.find({'user.id': user_id}, function(err, users) {
        if(err) throw err;

        items = users;
        return items;
    });
}

app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    wasMessageShown(app.locals.answerObj);

    console.log(req.user);
    var user;
    if(req.user.user.id){
        user = req.user;
    } else {
        user = getUser(req.user.item.user_id);
    }

    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user: user,
        messageSuccess: app.locals.answerObj.messageSuccess,
        messageFailure: app.locals.answerObj.messageFailure
    });
});
```

Comment: Typo?  `user.id` should be `user_id`?  Just going by you saying you were looking for `user_id`.

Comment: There are 3 id in your dbSchema. Which one you are trying to match?
1. `user: id`,
2. `item: id`,
3. `item: user_id`

Comment: No, it's not a typo, there are really 3 types of id's: user id, item id and user_id in item object (id of item creator).
Here I'm trying to find a user with id that matched with item.user_id.

Comment: Can you post your `UserSchema` to see the structure ?